# How to correct this python code (fill up a matrix row by row)?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I want to fill up the matrix called allsamples using elements in A. I wrote the following code, however, I got the error message: " allsamples[i,:]=[a1, a2, a3, a4]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0". How to correct the following code to make it work? Thanks!

```
 import numpy as np
A=[2, 4, 9, 10]
lA=len(A)
i=0
allsamples=np.zeros((lA^(lA),lA))
for a1 in A:
    for a2 in A:
        for a3 in A:
            for a4 in A:
                allsamples[i,:]=[a1, a2, a3, a4]
                i=i+1
print(allsamples)
```

Comment: Could you show a small example of what the expected output would be

Comment: @defladamouse Thanks! For example, if A=[2,4], then I want allsamples[1,:]=[2,2]   allsamples[2,:]=[2,4]   allsamples[3,:]=[4,2]  allsamples[4,:]=[4,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code is correct, the error is here `(lA^(lA),lA)`.  `^` is bitwise xor (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).  Modify it to `(lA**lA, lA)` and it runs without error.

Answer (score 1):

allsamples have a shape of (0,4). So it might be the problem. lA^(lA) gives zero.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly where the problem is. What I aimed for was lA to the power lA...